# Can we say 'she got out of her/the bed’ with a determiner?

Tags: idioms, determiners

*Bed* is being used as both the countable and uncountable meaning as in

> 1. Simon lay **in bed** thinking.
> 2. She **got into bed** and turned out the light.
>      (source: [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bed_1))

I wonder whether this *she got out of bed* can be the meaning of not just *she woke up*, but can imply this meaning: ‘*(having woken up an hour ago, and stayed in bed or on the bed) she got out of bed*’.

I mean, can *bed* be used as a countable noun without articles as in *she got out of bed* (question #1)? If it can, can we say *she got out of her/the bed* with determiners? (question #2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Question #1** is simple: Yes.

> She got out of bed.

Yes, that can mean that she got off her bed of laying there for some time.

**Question #2** is the tricky one.

Answering questions that ask, "Can you do X in English?" is difficult, because there are several factors at play. Depending on what X is, the answer is often:

1) Yes, you *can* – but that doesn't mean most native speakers *would*.
2) Yes, you *can* – but typically only in certain contexts when it makes sense.

I'm playing around with some sample sentences in my head, trying to figure out when a determiner would sound natural, and when it would sound out-of-place.

Here's what I've come up with:

> She tossed and turned for at least an hour after she woke from the disturbing dream. Finally, **she got out of bed and got dressed**. (*Sounds fine*)
>
> She tossed and turned for at least an hour after she woke from the disturbing dream. Finally, **she got out of her bed and got dressed**. (OPINION: *The word* her *isn't necessary, but it doesn't sound terribly awkward, either*)
>
> She tossed and turned for at least an hour after she woke from the disturbing dream. Finally, **she got out of his bed and got dressed**. (OPINION: *A determiner might actually be useful if a writer wanted to emphasize that she wasn't sleeping in her own bed*)
>
> She tossed and turned for at least an hour after she woke from the disturbing dream. Finally, **she got out of the bed and got dressed**. (OPINION: *The word* the *seems like its just begging to be removed; if she were in her own bed, I would omit it, although it might be okay if she was, say, sleeping in a hotel room*)

Also, determiners are actually *necessary* when preceding an adjective modifying *bed*:

> She tossed and turned for at least an hour after she woke from the disturbing dream. Finally, **she got out of the messy bed and got dressed**. (Sounds fine)
>
> She tossed and turned for at least an hour after she woke from the disturbing dream. Finally, **she got out of messy bed and got dressed**. (**Incorrect**; a determiner is needed here)

Comment: From your well-arranged account, I get an idea that if there is already implied definiteness, we need not use some article that would be “redundant”. (“The interpretation of bare role NPs invariably definite - CGEL,p.409”) Thank you for your refined answer.

Comment: What was she laying in her bed? Eggs? I suspect that you mean ***lying*** on/in her bed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I’m misunderstanding *Question #1*, but I believe that the answer is “No”. 
We would say

> All twelve children got out of bed.

or

> Everybody in the hotel got out of bed.

Even though these sentences are clearly referring to multiple beds,
we still say “bed” rather than “beds.” 
Compare to

> All twelve children wore hats.

or

> Everybody in the hotel got into sailboats.

“Bed” is used in phrases like ***go to bed*** and *[they are] **in bed***, similar to

- “in jail” / “in prison”
- “in school”
- “on vacation” / (Br.E. only) “on holiday”
- (Br.E. only) “in hospital”

I believe that, in these examples with no article, “bed” is uncountable. 
Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right, *bed* is definitely not a countable noun in this case. If it is a noun, it's used in the sense of the concept of *being at rest or asleep*, which typically takes place *in bed*. I'd say *go to bed* and *get out of bed* are phrasal verb constructions, because they have quite specific meanings and usages, but *bed* is uncountable either way.